# Enable switch with two pair of black and red wires

Tags: wiring, lighting

I am in the UK, I have a switch that has been disconnected.
The rose that this is connected to has the red wires into the "Loop" part.  (*There are two ceiling roses connected to a single switch*).

I need to enable this but don't know if the red wires or the black wires need to go into the switch?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of said wiring rose please?

Comment: Thanks.  Added the image, for additional information there are two ceiling roses connected to a single switch.

Comment: Wait a minute...is that a single pole or a double pole switch you have there? It seems the last installer did something *super* screwy...perhaps a photo of the other rose would help?

Comment: Not sure about the switch, it was there when i bought the house.  Added picture of second rose.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a very dodgy bit of wiring to me. I would strongly suggest you get a professional in to sort it out.

Having said that I can make a guess at how it's connected, and how you can get it working, but you should check my assumptions for yourself.

The first thing you must do is find out which cable is power in to the system (probably one of the two in the first rose, should be connected to N and Loop), then work out where the other cables run. My guess is that of the two cables in the switch back box, one runs to each rose.

If you don't know how to do that or my guesses are wrong, STOP and call a professional.

If I'm right, then connecting the loose red wire into the bottom terminal of the switch will re-enable the lights, but they may behave oddly as it looks like they're wired in series and so each bulb will only get 120V instead of the expected 240V.

The correct wiring should be from the second rose to the first with red and black in the L and N terminals, and only one cable to the switch from the first rose, with red and black in Loop and L respectively, (the black should have a red band applied)

Again this looks like whoever wired it in the first place did not understand what they were doing, and should be fixed by a professional.

Comment: Thanks - that is pretty much the conclusion i came to also.  Appreciate your time to respond.